Struggling writer gets his first book published because of his Daughter
The person is a struggling writer. He somehow had to take care of a six year girl child (which he didn't like initially) but soon started liking her company. The six year girl seems to be pretty mature and helped this writer find a nice girlfriend. Also, she became the main reason behind his success.

Could you provide additional details? When did this movie came out? When did you watch it? What language it was in? What main heroes looked like?
